# Github Actions CI with mikepenz/action-junit-report@v3 occurs Failed to create checks using the provided token

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

[image]

I am getting this error. Accordingly, the test results are not registered in PR or expressed in other ways.

The settings are:

```
name: register test
uses: mikepenz/action-junit-report@v3
if: always()
with:
  report_paths: '**/build/test-results/test/TEST-*.xml'
  token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Can you tell me which part is the problem? I read almost all the official documentation but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Did you already checked out [issue 23](https://github.com/mikepenz/action-junit-report/issues/23) mentioned in the warning? This seems like a good place to start. Also the `permissions` block could be interesting for your workflow file.

Answer (score 0):

Your job requires additional `write` permission, it's described in [PR run permissions](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/junit-report-action#pr-run-permissions).

> The action requires write permission on the checks. If the GA token is
> read-only (this is a repository configuration) please enable write
> permission via:
>
> ```
> permissions:
>   checks: write
> ```

An alternative way is to grant the write and read permissions globally. According to [this comment, it's not recommended](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/57244#discussioncomment-7177474), but can help you to find the solution.
To do so, in your repository settings, go to:

1. Settings
2. Actions
3. General
4. Workflow permissions
5. Select "Read and write permissions"